# Shiny (Rstudio) apps not working

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am working on the [Shiny tutorial for RStudio](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/#Go%20Further).  I updated my RStudio, as indicated in the tutorial. The current version I have is 0.98.945.  When I run the supplied examples like `runExample("01_hello")`, it opens my web browser and shows all the HTML content, but does not seem to be processing the R code.

When I proceed further in the tutorial for creating my own app `runApp("App-1")`, I get an error message on the web page:  ERROR: could not find function "fluidPage".  After some sleuthing, I found a posting on another site indicating that I need to download the developer version of shiny from GitHub, found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny#installation).  I ran the code snippet for that installation -- and still no luck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After updating Rstudio to the newest version redo the install.packages("shiny") and library("shiny"). Once you do this it should eliminate the need to manually do the runApp code and a button should appear were the run button usually is that says run app. before you can click run app though you have to set your working directory to the location were you have saved your server.R and ui.R by going to session -> set working directory -> choose directory. chose the folder location then click run app.

Edit: there should be no need for you to run that code from GitHub

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After installing shiny, I had to restart Rstuido for the "Run App" button to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had also some wired troubles when starting using shiny. Finally I got all fixed by removing all my previous libraries and installations and re-install only the latest versions